# Objective-c import function from AppDelegate not working

Tags: objective-c, xcode, function, appdelegate

In my AppDelegate.m I've written a download data from url function. I am trying to
receive the function into my bootController but it throws me te error. What am I missing?

> No known class method for selector
>   'downloadDataFromURL:withCompletionHandler:'

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you declare the method in `AppDelegate.h` ?

Comment: Yes, but I see not in the right way! I thought just declare the function as + (void)downloadDataFromUrl was enough, but I had to declare the hole line I see. If you make your comment as a answer to declare the function in .h I make it as accepted :)

Comment: Don't put code in AppDelegate! The AppDelegate should only be responsible for launching the App and reacting on application state changes. Download code in the AppDelegate is really poor design.

Comment: It was quick just for test. I will create a custom class for this. But thanks anyway to notice ! :)

Comment: @Freshtea I'm glad to do that.

Comment: Where to put it really depends on the size of the app.

Comment: @uchuugaka An App can't be so small that it makes sense to put it into AppDelegate. To create a class has zero cost in Objective-C and a lot of benefits. It's an object oriented language after all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should declare the method in its header.

`+ (void)downloadDataFromUrl:(NSURL *)url withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(NSData *data))completionHandler;`